# MySQLi gives no result after inserting emails from text file and then checking them back

Tags: php, mysqli

I have inserted couple of emails from a text file into database using mysqli. They get inserted though. Now when I am checking them back I am not getting any result.

Query for inserting emails from text file.

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'new.txt' INTO TABLE $table FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n' (email)";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($connection),E_USER_ERROR);
```

Query for checking them back using email not working.

```
$query = "SELECT email FROM $table WHERE email='email'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$email = $row['email'];
echo $email.'<br >';
```

Query for checking them back using id is working.

```
$query = "SELECT email FROM $table WHERE id='1'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$email = $row['email'];
echo $email.'<br >';
```

Output of this query shows a white space at the end of email but when I check in database there is no white space.

Please see why this is not working and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Is the query correct? Do you get any sql error(s)?

Comment: yes query correct, no errors

Comment: What does the `email` column contain? Are you sure that the equality comparison of `email='email'` is your best search option?

Comment: _“Output of this query shows a white space at the end of email but when I check in database there is no white space.”_ – please use `var_dump` instead of echo, that should show you _exactly_ what your variable contains (best viewed as plain text, so browser->show source).

Answer (score 1):

Your code cannot work. mysqli_query returns a  mysqli_result object.

You can use mysqli_fetch_array to get the data:

```
$query = "SELECT email FROM $table WHERE email='email'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$email = $row['email'];
echo $email.'<br >';
```

By the way: PHP will tell you "undefined variable $row" when you change your error-reporting settings.